# Using Session with Threads in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, session

I want to use a Session object through all my pages in my asp.net site, first I Save an object in my session like this, this line of code is in an HttpHandler

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["DocumnetInfo"] = doc;
```

after that I created a a thread to manipulate this doc and send the session as parameter to the thread as follows

```
            HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
               // HttpContext.Current = ctx;
                SomeMethod(ctx);
            }));
            t.Start();
```

and In SomeMethod I read the Session as follows:

```
private void SomeMethod ( HttpContext  ctx)
{

    DocResultsBLL doc = (DocResultsBLL)ctx.Session["DocumnetInfo"];
    // Here is the logic of the manipulation
    // then save the doc in the session back
    ctx.Session["DocumnetInfo"]=doc;
    Response.Redirect("ResultsPage.aspx");
}
```

The problem is that I couldn't read the session in the results page.. HttpContext.Current is null.
1-How can I work with session , to send it to a thread, then to get it back outside the thread.
2- Is there any other scenario other than session that is better?
3- How can I stop the Thread if the Client Closed his browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only you can do is like passing http context see the following link and you will understand why its not possible to have session available in multi threading application.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webtopics/archive/2009/01/30/why-can-t-i-execute-two-requests-from-the-same-session-simultaneously-for-an-asp-net-application.aspx

Comment: any other solution? @Jalpesh Vadgama

Comment: I don't think so it will allowed only thing you can do is to pass current context in argument of method.

Comment: I did that between the page and the Business layer , but what if I am opening another page ? I need session, or store data in db. and I don't want to store data in a db. So I need reliable solution that replaces the session, thank @Jalpesh Vadgama